# How to join multiple xmpp rooms with one stanza?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

When I login to my chat application I need to join about 20 rooms, but it will take about 1 minute to finish join all room by sending 20 join stanza. I wonder there is a way that I can join 20 rooms just by sending only 1 stanza with 20 room ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible using [XEP-0033 Extended Stanza Addressing](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html). You can see how to do that on this question: [How to join multiple rooms by just sending one  message to ejabberd server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782236/559289).